# VB.NET - frame capture issue and syncing audio with video using ffmpeg issue

Tags: vb.net, ffmpeg

I have a code in VB.NET that capture fullscreen images of the desktops at regular intervals (code runs in timer tick event of 20ms) Within the same ticker event I even capture the audio.
Code to capture the screenshots

```
    Filenum.Text = Filenum.Text + 1
    Dim screensize As Size = New Size(My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width, My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height)
    Dim BMP As New Bitmap(My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width, My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height)
    Dim ga As System.Drawing.Graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(BMP)
    ga.CopyFromScreen(New Point(0, 0), New Point(0, 0), screensize)
    Cursor.Draw(ga, New Rectangle(Cursor.Position, Cursor.Size))
    Dim fileDiro As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory + "\Recorder\VidShots-" + DT + "\img"

    Dim frame As String = Filenum.Text
    BMP.Save(fileDiro + frame + ".png")
```

I notice the above code runs OK (not too much as expected) when doing regular recording of desktop but when recording a video or fast motion capture, it fails to generate enough frames to create a decent clip.

```
'''' Code exclusively for Audio recording - Start audio recording - added 22/09/2013

 mciSendString("open new Type waveaudio Alias recsound", "", 0, 0)
    mciSendString("record recsound", "", 0, 0)

 '''' Code exclusively for Audio recording - Stop audio recording - added 22/09/2013
    Using w As New IO.FileStream( _
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory + "\Recorder\sound.mp3", _
                    IO.FileMode.Create _
                )
        w.SetLength(64000)
    End Using

    Dim fP As String
    fP = My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\Recorder\sound.mp3"
    mciSendString("save recsound " & Chr(34) & fP & Chr(34), "", 0, 0)
    mciSendString("close recsound", "", 0, 0)
    My.Computer.Audio.Stop()
```

The problem is when I try to mux together the audio and video using ffmpeg.exe, more often than not, the audio is out of sync with the video generated. Below are examples of the two ffmpeg statements that are executed.

```
 Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo(My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\ffmpeg.exe")
       startInfo.Arguments = "-r " + max.ReadLine + " -analyzeduration 2147483647 -probesize 2147483647 -i Recorder/" + x + "/img%d.png -r 12 -b:v 900K Recorder/" + x + "/video.avi"
        Debug.Print(startInfo.Arguments.ToString)

        p = Process.Start(startInfo)
        p.WaitForExit()
        'Process.Start(My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\ffmpeg.exe", "-r 10 -analyzeduration 2147483647 -probesize 2147483647 -i Recorder/" + x + "/img%d.png -r 50 Recorder/" + x + "/video.avi"))
        Process.Start(My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\ffmpeg.exe", "-i Recorder/" + x + "/video.avi -i Recorder/sound.mp3 -map 0 -map 1 -codec copy -shortest Recorder/" + x + "/video1.avi")
        Debug.Print("-i Recorder/" + x + "/video.avi -i Recorder/sound.mp3 -map 0 -map 1 -codec copy -shortest Recorder/" + x + "/video1.avi")
```

Could someone please help in getting the audio and video in sync?